# What is the purpose of thunkToPromise in the co coroutine lib?

Tags: javascript, promise, coroutine, thunk

I know `co` is kind of outdated but I am still interested in how it works. I find it hard to understand the purpose of the `thunkToPromise` function, though:

```
function thunkToPromise(fn) {
  var ctx = this;
  return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
    fn.call(ctx, function (err, res) {
      if (err) return rej(err);
      if (arguments.length > 2) res = slice.call(arguments, 1);
      res(res);
    });
  });
}
```

A thunk is a function without parameters, but `fn` is still called with one argument. In addition there is this weird recursive call `res(res)`, which usually results in a stack overflow. What's going on here? How would I apply `thunkToPromise` so that it does something meaningful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A thunk is a function without parameters

No. A thunk is a function that takes only a callback to forward its result. It does take no *data* parameters, that's true, only an "output parameter".

> In addition there is this weird recursive call `res(res)`

It's not recursive, it's just broken. Someone mixed up `result` and `resolve`. Did you find this in a current release of the library?

Comment: Do you mean a thunk in the context of coroutines always expects a continuation? That would make sense.

Comment: `res(res)` was indeed my fault, when I thoughtless used `find/replace all` in sublime. Sorry for that!

Comment: @reify Yes, a thunk is a value that needs a continuation.